# CultureInfo.LCID returns incorrect LocaleID

Tags: c#, .net-core, razor-pages

This code:

```
new CultureInfo("es-ES").LCID
```

returns the value:

```
3082
```

Is this a bug in Dot NET Core?

Comment: And which one is correct? 1034? On [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo) there are international and traditional columns, check how instance is created.

Comment: Evidently, I am receiving the International when I require the Traditional. Any idea how I can request the traditional? I'm not sure how to convert "es-ES" into a hex value.

Comment: `new CultureInfo("es-ES_tradnl").LCID` (I found string [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-lcid/a9eac961-e77d-41a6-90a5-ce1a8b0cdb9c)) ?